# For each String S, print 's even-indexed characters, followed by a space, followed by 's odd-indexed characters

Tags: python

Im trying to do hackerrank challenge but this code is solving 3/10 of the test case.
The challenge is Given a string, S , of N length that is indexed from 0 to N-1 , print its even-indexed and odd-indexed characters as space-separated strings on a single line. Note: 0 is considered to be an even index

```
import sys
cases = int(sys.stdin.readline())
for x in range(cases):
    str= sys.stdin.readline()
    str= [str[x] for x in range(len(str)) if x%2==0 and str[x]!="\n"] +[" "] + [str[x] for x in range(len(str)) if x%2!=0]
    str="".join(str)
    print(str)
```

Need some help.
Thanks

Comment: what's wrong with the code?  How is it not working?  Also, are you intentionally trying to solve the problem in one line of code?

Comment: @Kos sorry what im trying to do is Given a string, S , of N length  that is indexed from 0 to N-1 , print its even-indexed and odd-indexed characters as  space-separated strings on a single line.

Note: 0 is considered to be an even index.

Comment: @KevinWang i dont know what's the problem but when i submit the code to hackerrank it says it failed 7 out of the 10 test cases. And yes im trying to solve it in one line of code. Thanks for replying

Comment: have you tried making your own testcases to try to find instances where your code doesn't work as expected?

Comment: I solved it. I replaced str= [str[x] for x in range(len(str)) if x%2==0 and str[x]!="\n"] +[" "] + [str[x] for x in range(len(str)) if x%2!=0] for str= "".join(str[0::2]) + " " + "".join(str[1::2}) and also added the .strip() to str= sys.stdin.readline(). Thanks for the help @KevinWang

Answer (score 0):

The solution depends on how you index characters.

If the first character is index 0:

```
s = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" 
r = "".join(s[0::2]) + " " + "".join(s[1::2])

print(r)
acegikmoqsuwy bdfhjlnprtvxz
```

If the first character is index 1:

```
r = "".join(s[1::2]) + " " + "".join(s[0::2])

print(r)
bdfhjlnprtvxz acegikmoqsuwy
```